# ASP.NET MVC resolving concrete types without any DI code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a controller with a dependency on `ImageReader` and `ImageWriter`. I am using constructor injection to inject these types into the controller:

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly ImageReader _imageReader;
    private readonly ImageWriter _imageWriter;

    public MyController(ImageReader imageReader, ImageWriter imageWriter)
    {
        _imageReader = imageReader;
        _imageWriter = imageWriter;
    }

    // more code ...
}
```

`ImageReader` and `ImageWriter` are classed with no dependency (i.e. they can be initialized without any constructor arguments).

**Question**

I had this code running perfectly fine... but I just realized I had forgotten to register `ImageReader` in my DI code (using Ninject):

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    // some code....

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        // I had forgotten to include ImageReader here
        kernel.Bind<ImageWriter>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

How is it possible that the code was running fine? Does ASP.NET MVC know how to resolve concrete types on its own?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and .NET 4.6

Comment: I believe Ninject defaults back to Activator for concrete classes that can be initialized without dependencies. Only in this case it would be the same as transient as a new instance will be used for each request. I'm assuming you are using Ninjects IDependencyResolver implementation.

Comment: Check https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/dependency-injection-with-ninject#skipping-the-type-binding-bit--implicit-self-binding-of-concrete-types

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nkosi. That explains it. I thought it is MVC which is resolving the type... it turned out to be ninject.

Comment: And to prove it. Change one of the injected dependencies to an interface and don't register it. It will blow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @Nkosi, I found the answer.

This is because of Ninject's [implicit self binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/dependency-injection-with-ninject#skipping-the-type-binding-bit--implicit-self-binding-of-concrete-types):

> if the type you’re resolving is a concrete type (like Samurai above),
>   Ninject will automatically create a default association via a
>   mechanism called implicit self binding. It’s as if there’s a
>   registration like this:
>
> `Bind<Samurai>().To<Samurai>();`

In my example above, since `ImageReader` is a concrete type, ninject would resolve it automatically.